# How to store items in a sorted list in MongoDb?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am building a publication-rotation solution with MongoDb.

The client has, for example, 1000 products, and at any one time, 200 of these products should be available to subscribers. The rest (800), should be in a rotation pattern, where every day one product is published and another unpublished, such that after 800 days a full rotation has occurred.

My initial idea was to simply store ID references in two new collections:

```
products_published
products_unpublished
```

And then, every day, `shift()` an item from `products_published` and `unshift()` it into `products_unpublished`, while at the same time `pop()` an item from `products_unpublished` and `push()` it into `products_published`:

[image]

A very naive attempt at rotation, maybe. But it seemed simple.

The final requirement is that this order of rotation must be editable via some UI.

The problem lies in that MongoDb doesn't seem to guarantee natural order, nor is it easy to insert documents at exact locations in a collection, move them around, etc.

I do not really want to maintain my own `order` property on my documents, as with each rotation I would have to increment every single document's `order`.

I also considered keeping all this data in a single document with two arrays, because arrays inside documents themselves *do* preserve order in a safe way. However, this felt dirty and prone to future problems.

After lots of Googling, I haven't found a good answer about how to maintain an ordered collection with MongoDb.

I do not want to use hard-coded dates, as the rotation frequency may change in the future to twice a day, three times a day, etc.

**Any recommendations?**

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 properties: `order` and `published_date`.
The former is for users to define the initial order. The later is for you to rotate.

The query to get the next one:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({published_date: 1, order: 1}).limit(1)
```

The push/pop update:

```
db.collection.update({_id}, {$set:{published_date: new ISODate()}})
```

On `order` change, delete all `published_date`s for new order to have effect.

The example:

```
// initial data
db.collection.insert([
  {_id:1, order:2},
  {_id:2, order:1},
  {_id:3, order:3}
])

// pick the first document
db.collection.find({}).sort({published_date: 1, order: 1}).limit(1)
// returns you {_id:2, order:1}

// rotating it:
db.collection.update({_id:2}, {$set:{published_date: new ISODate()}})

// pick the first document
db.collection.find({}).sort({published_date: 1, order: 1}).limit(1)
// returns you {_id:1, order:2}

// rotating it:
db.collection.update({_id:1}, {$set:{published_date: new ISODate()}})

// pick the first document
db.collection.find({}).sort({published_date: 1, order: 1}).limit(1)
// returns you {_id:3, order:3}

// rotating it:
db.collection.update({_id:1}, {$set:{published_date: new ISODate()}})

// pick the first document
db.collection.find({}).sort({published_date: 1, order: 1}).limit(1)
// returns you {_id:2, order:1, published_date: 2018-02-27T18:28:20.330Z}

etc, etc, etc until end of days at 15:30:08 on Sunday, December 4th in the year 292,277,026,596 AC
```

If you don't like date as a natural autoincrementing value, you can go with order field alone.

The push/pop update will then be:

```
db.collection.update({_id}, {$inc:{order: <number of documents in rotation>}})
```

But it will require some housekeeping to `$dec` the counter time to time, and complicate shifting of a single document.

Alternatively you may consider to keep the IDs within a single document, rather than a collection:

```
{
    refs: [
        product_id,
        product_id,
        product_id,
    ]
}
```

if it fits into 16MB limit of a single document.

The order of elements in the array is preserved: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt, and you can use regular [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)/[$pop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) updates

Comment: I do not want to use hard-coded dates, as the rotation frequency may change in the future to twice a day, three times a day, etc.

Comment: Also, I don't think your solution even works. Users need to be able to modify the rotation order... Not just the "initial" order.

Comment: ISODate has millis precision. Sorry if the name is misleading.

Comment: Messing with rotation order **during** rotation is a questionable feature, but I leave it for business to deal with consequences. How do you re-define order during rotation? Shifting one item in the list? updating order for the whole pink stack?

Comment: I know it has millis precision. I'd rather keep rotation interval logic in a separate rotator-microservice, and just preserve rotation _order_ at a database level. The rotation is constant, so of course any reordering would take place during rotation. The easiest way would be to simply swap the position of any two products.

Comment: Anything stops you to swap `published_date` on the 2 selected documents? Anyway I have added few alternatives for you to consider, but frankly, all of them are less flexible than the date-based approach.

Comment: An array is the most flexible... I'm asking how to achieve this in MongoDb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165921/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-isaac-hinman).